# Вложенность свойств в выборке Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Вывожу товары в Битриксе как в документации

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID","NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","PROPERTY_*"); 
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>5,"ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y"); 
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
```

тут ещё добавил "PROPERTY_*", чтобы вывести все свойства

а как в $arFilter добавить условие по свойству?

само условие вложенное в массиве, т.е. PROPERTY_ID" => 64 не получится использовать

type->id

я пробую так

```
Array("PROPERTY_TYPE" => Array("PROPERTY_ID" => 64))
```

или так

```
Array("PROPERTY_TYPE_ID" => 64)
```

и не выходит..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правльно понимаю, фильтр по свойству, например, такой

```
$arFilter = Array(
"IBLOCK_ID"=>GOODS, 
"ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", 
"ACTIVE"=>"Y", 
"=PROPERTY_CML2_ARTIKUL_VALUE"=>$p_title
);
```